# After 3 mistake attepmts, i want to break the operation by giving another error message. (in python)

Tags: python-3.x

```
captcha1=input("Setup a captcha: ")
print("captcha is: " + captcha1)
captcha2=''
while captcha2 != captcha1:
    print("You have to enter same captcha to login")
    captcha2=input("Re-enter captcha:" )
    if captcha2==captcha1:
        print ("You are logged in")
    else:
        print("Invalid captcha")
```

something like below that will display after each incorrect attempt. i.e. count in error message keeps on increasing and when it meets certain message the programme terminates.

```
A="Invalid captcha"
i=1
while i<4:
    print(A + " " + str(i))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, simplified examples to support your explanation, and code/configuration/links you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Finally done by myself

```
A = 0
captcha1=input("Setup a captcha: ")
print("captcha is: " + captcha1)
captcha2=''

while captcha2 != captcha1:
    if A == 3:
        break
    print("You have to enter same captcha to login")
    captcha2=input("Re-enter captcha:" )
    if captcha2==captcha1:
        print ("You are logged in")
    else:
        B = A
        A = B + 1
        if A<3:
            print ("Invalid captcha")
        else:
            print ("Account blocked")
```